# How to set a proper connection string for EF DB First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, ef-database-first

I have an ArgumentException : Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.
I tried many things, read many posts. I dont know what to do...
This is my CS :

```
<add name="CDPContext"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/CDP_Model.csdl|
                                res://*/CDP_Model.ssdl|
                                res://*/CDP_Model.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient
                       provider connection string='Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
                                                    AttachDbFilename=\CDP.mdf;
                                                    Initial Catalog=CDP;
                                                    Integrated Security=True;
                                                    MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
                                                    App=EntityFramework'"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the connection string you provided above is for model first.

to use connection string for code first you could write your connection string as below

```
 <add name="CDPContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
AttachDbFilename=\CDP.mdf;
Initial Catalog=CDP;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and also go to you context, if there is a throw exception in it, just remove it.

Comment: I use database first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" is the wrong provider for DB First
instead use providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" to access the db using the EDM...